# Send Data From Controller to View Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have an function `get()` on my controller. This function I use to get data from database and I save it to `$data` variable.
It's possible to call `get()` function on another function and I send the `$data` variable to the view? I want to make two view, one is classic and another one is modern view.
This is my code:

```
public function get()
{
    $data['all'] = $this->genbamodel->getAll();
    $data['delay'] = $this->genbamodel->getDelay();
    $data['ontime'] = $this->genbamodel->getOntime();
    $data['ahead'] = $this->genbamodel->getAhead();
    $data['unloading'] = $this->genbamodel->getUnloading();
    $data['topdelay'] = $this->genbamodel->getTopDelay();
    $data['topahead'] = $this->genbamodel->getTopAhead();

    $data['jumlah'] =  count($this->genbamodel->getID())+1;


    for ($j=1; $j < $data['jumlah']; $j++) { 

        $datas['lalax'.$j] = $this->genbamodel->getRecord($j);

        $data['lala'.$j] = array_reverse($datas['lalax'.$j]);
    }

    $data['time'] = $this->genbamodel->getTime();


}

public function home_classic()
{
    $this->get();
    $this->load->view('home_classic',$data);
}
public function home_modern()
{
    $this->get();
    $this->load->view('home_modern',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you :

Your `get()` method should `return` $data

```
public function get()
{
    $data['all'] = $this->genbamodel->getAll();
    $data['delay'] = $this->genbamodel->getDelay();
    $data['ontime'] = $this->genbamodel->getOntime();
    $data['ahead'] = $this->genbamodel->getAhead();
    $data['unloading'] = $this->genbamodel->getUnloading();
    $data['topdelay'] = $this->genbamodel->getTopDelay();
    $data['topahead'] = $this->genbamodel->getTopAhead();

    $data['jumlah'] =  count($this->genbamodel->getID())+1;


    for ($j=1; $j < $data['jumlah']; $j++) { 

        $datas['lalax'.$j] = $this->genbamodel->getRecord($j);

        $data['lala'.$j] = array_reverse($datas['lalax'.$j]);
    }

    $data['time'] = $this->genbamodel->getTime();

   return $data;
}
```

in `home_classic()` do it like this

```
public function home_classic()
{
    $data = $this->get();
    $this->load->view('home_classic',$data);
}
```

in `home_modern()` do the same

```
public function home_modern()
{
    $data = $this->get();
    $this->load->view('home_modern',$data);
}
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view